# Front menu not showing subitems

Tags: theming, navigation, 9

I've generated my menu based on the menu template from the stable theme

```
{% macro menu_links(items, attributes, menu_level) %}
  {% import _self as menus %}
  {% if items %}
    {% if menu_level == 0 %}
<ul{{ attributes }}>
  {% else %}
  <ul>
    {% endif %}
    {% for item in items %}
      <li{{ item.attributes.addClass('sidebar-item') }}>
        {{ link(item.title, item.url) }}
        {% if item.below %}
          {{ menus.menu_links(item.below, attributes, menu_level + 1) }}
        {% endif %}
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
  {% endif %}
  {% endmacro %}
```

First level are working fine, but the subitems are not showing, cause **below** is always empty.

I've already checked the number of items to show, it has no limit

[image]

[image]

This is my menu, with the subchild

[image]

I'm using drupal 9.3.2 and PHP8.0.8

Comment: You need to check “Expanded” next to the parent menu items (or arrange the same via code)

Comment: Yes, that's it, thanks a lot !